# Search template suggestions from a module

Tags: 7, theming, search

I have created a custom search module that integrates with Drupal 7 Search Interface. My module is called `history_search` and in the module I have two files: `history_search.module` and `history_search.info`.

These are the contents of my `history_search.module`:

```
<?php

function history_search_search_info()
{
    return array(
        'title' => 'History',
        'path' => 'history',
        'conditions_callback' => 'history_search_search_conditions_callback',
    );
}
```

When I try to use it, it works correctly: Drupal creates a search tab for me and uses the results data I provide. However, I can't figure out how to get it to use my template suggestion for a single search result. I created a file in my module's folder called `search-result--history_search.tpl.php`, however it doesn't seem to be used when I perform searches in my module. However, if I place this file in my theme, then it suddenly works fine with no problems.

So my question is, how do I get Drupal to use `search-result--history_search.tpl.php` when I place it in my module's folder?

Comment: Your after YOURMODULE_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) function.

Comment: @AlexGill did you mean [`hook_theme_registry_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) ?

Comment: Ahhh bugger, yes indeed, good spot Beebee!

Comment: Great suggestions guys, I solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @AlexGill and @Beebee I was able to figure out what's the actual suggestion name for my template file. Here's how I solved it:

```
<?php

function history_search_theme()
{
    return array(
        'search_result__history_search' => array(
            'template' => 'search-result--history_search',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'history_search'),
            'base hook' => 'search_result',
        ),
    );
}
```